# Pulling info from one of several columns

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, calculated-column-formula, metadata

[image]
When documents are added to my library, one of 4 approval workflows runs based on the metadata entered on the item (if the document is for Sales, the Sales approval workflow runs, etc).  I would like have one column that displays the status of the approval workflow. Since currently, the status of the workflow would appear in one of 4 columns (for whichever workflow is running) - i would like to condense this information into 1 column for simplicity. Is there a way to write a formula (or any other method) that would display the status of the workflow in 1 column for all items?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, You could put these 4 approval workflows in one workflow, like this:

[image]

Comment: I added a screenshot that shows my current workflow. This one workflow kicks off one of 4 approval work flows based on the "area" value (i haven't created the last 2 area approval workflows, but you get the idea).  Is this the same as what you are recommending? It seems a bit different but i am not sure what i am doing wrong. My current process is using a total of 5 workflows (4 approvals and 1 to kick one off). Are you suggesting everything can be combined into 1 workflow total?

Comment: can you please clarify if i am doing the same thing you are suggesting or if i am doing something different?

Comment: Yes, it is possible to combine them in 1 workflow if the default action "Start Aproval process" is al tha is needed.

Comment: Otherwise:
- add a column to the list (to hold the workflow status, single line)
- add an action just before you start the sub workflow which updates the status column (ex. "Approval for Service started" (I guess you configured it so that the main workflow waits until the sub workflows finishes (default config)?)

Comment: Or just add action in sub workflow which updates the custom status column